# jQuery select elements of one class within another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have elements with the class "some_class" inside various divs that have individual classes/ids, like in this example:

```
<div class="alpha">
    <p class="some_class">Text</p>
    <p class="some_class">More text</p>
</div>
<div class="beta">
    <p class="some_class">Even more text</p>
    <p class="some_class">Bored now</p>
</div>
```

I can use jQuery to select all elements with the class "some_class" and toggle another class like this:

```
$('.toggle_button').click(function () {
    $('.some_class').toggleClass('another_class');
    //do more stuff
});
```

How would I write a function that toggles only those elements of "some_class" that are within the "alpha"/"beta" divs?

Comment: @Tushar Gupta has got it spot on, I recently did this tutorial that will make this kind of stuff make a whole load more sense... [**Try jQuery**](http://try.jquery.com/levels/1/challenges/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) , [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.alpha').children('.some_class').toggleClass('another_class');
```

---

[Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('.alpha > .some_class').toggleClass('another_class')
```

---

```
$('.alpha .some_class').toggleClass('another_class');
```

---

[Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('.alpha .some_class,.beta .some_class').toggleClass('another_class');


$('.alpha,.beta').find('.some_class').toggleClass('another_class');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.alpha,.beta').find('.some_class').toggleClass('another_class');
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AFev9/2/)***

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.alpha .some_class, .beta .some_class').toggleClass('another_class');
```